# How to use data collection in nested loop

Tags: java, loops, nested

I can collect all of the input data, but I just can't seem to do anything with it. I would like to print all of data or add or subtract the numbers, perform calculations. I am not sure how to work with nested data.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Names {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many students do you want to enter?");
        String[] names = new String[2];
        for (int stnumber = 0; stnumber < 2; stnumber++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the first student " + (stnumber + 1));
            names[stnumber] = input.next();

            String[] quiz = new String[2];

            for (int qznumber = 0; qznumber < 2; qznumber++) {
                System.out.println("Enter quiz mark " + (qznumber + 1));
                quiz[qznumber] = input.next();
            }
            String[] midterm = new String[1];
            for (int mtnumber = 0; mtnumber < 1; mtnumber++) {
                System.out.println("Enter midterm mark " + (mtnumber + 1));
                midterm[mtnumber] = input.next();
            }

            String[] myfinal = new String[1];
            for (int fnnumber = 0; fnnumber < 1; fnnumber++) {
                System.out.println("Enter final mark " + (fnnumber + 1));
                myfinal[fnnumber] = input.next();
            }

        }
        input.close();

        System.out.println("The students marks are");
        for (int stnumber = 0; stnumber < 2; stnumber++) {
            System.out.println(names[stnumber]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take care to properly format your code, it will make things much easier for those who will try to help you. It will also help you, when trying to identify possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a `class` to represent a Student:

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    String[] quizzes;
    String[] midterms;
    String[] finals;
}
```

Then, you will need a constructor to declare a new instance of a Student, here is an exmaple:

```
public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.quizzes = new String[2];
    this.midterms = new String[2];
    this.finals = new String[1];
}
```

Now you can create a new student in your main method like this:

```
Student newStudent = new Student("put the name here");
```

And store the quizzes, midterms, etc in that instance of the Student:

```
newStudent.midterms[0] = "midterm 1 grade";
```

Comment: OK I tried your example, but I think I need help because I get "error: class, interface, or enum expected"   Class, then Constructor, and then public void main seems to be the order I'm seeing online

Comment: @Newbe You need to put the constructor in the Student class, and the two examples on the bottom go in your main method in the loops

Comment: So the Student class would look like:

public class Student {
    String name;
    String[] quizzes;
    String[] midterms;
    String[] finals;
}

 
public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.quizzes = new String[2];
    this.midterms = new String[2];
    this.finals = new String[1];

Comment: @Newbe You need to put the constructor inside of the class